# Unable to parse JSON error using Twitterizer TwitterStatus.Show method

Tags: json, twitterizer

Running this code:

```
var statusResponse = TwitterStatus.Show(tweet.Id);
```

gives an error message: `Unable to parse JSON` in the `statusResponse` object and the `ResponseObject` comes back as `null`.

Not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same issue today. It seems that you reference a newer version of `Newtonsoft.Json` in your project (or maybe an other NuGet package included it).

The problem can be fixed by using the `Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.5.0` library that is shipped with the Twitterizer project. It needs to be that exact version.